# Showing an Image with onClick Listener Event

Tags: java, android, xml, onclicklistener

I've got very little android dev experience (thankfully there's stackoverflow.  been helping me a lot).  What I'm trying to do is have an imageview show up when a specific menu option is clicked.  I've got the menu/submenu working properly and I know that I can make the image invisible with `android:visibility="invisible"` and I think I can make it visible in java code with `imageView.visiblity="visible"` I think (if not please correct me).  I was told that I could use an "onClickListener event" to do this but the documentation that I've read have been of no help to me. 
 If anyone can please help me, it would be greatly appreciated.

Please refer to the following photos and my Java/XML code.

[image: how it's supposed to start]
[image: after clicking + button on the bottom]
[image: after clicking "Plain Image"]
[image: after clicking either option (also the background should be dimmed, no idea how to do that)]
My Java code so far (also I've created my menu/submenu in Java, not XML.  I don't know if that's bad practice but hopefully someone will tell me):

```
package com.example.android.postvu;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton;
import android.support.design.widget.Snackbar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.view.ContextMenu;
import android.view.SubMenu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

   FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();

    //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


public void myOnClickMethod(View v) {
    registerForContextMenu(v);
    openContextMenu(v);
}

final int CONTEXT_MENU_VIEW = 1;
final int CONTEXT_MENU_EDIT = 2;
final int MENU_SORT = 3;
final int MENU_SORT_BY_NAME = 4;
final int MENU_SORT_BY_ADDRESS = 5;


@Override
public void onCreateContextMenu (ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Options");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXT_MENU_VIEW, Menu.NONE, "Take Photo");
    menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXT_MENU_EDIT, Menu.NONE, "Photo Album");
    SubMenu sub=menu.addSubMenu(Menu.NONE, MENU_SORT, Menu.NONE, "Plain Image");
    sub.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_SORT_BY_NAME, Menu.NONE, "GridVu");
    sub.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_SORT_BY_ADDRESS, Menu.NONE, "Story");
    }
}
```

My XML code so far:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_main"
tools:context="com.example.android.postvu.MainActivity">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:contentDescription="@string/background"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/grid"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="7dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="7dp"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="@string/image_text_editor"
    android:textColor="@android:color/black"
    android:textSize="28sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    tools:text="Image Text Editor"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />


<Button
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:background="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:onClick="myOnClickMethod"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textView"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.98"
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="450dp"
    android:layout_height="450dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/white_background"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/button"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/textView"
    app:srcCompat="@mipmap/white" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: do you want to show/hide the ImageView on menu item click

Comment: yeah. basically when someone clicks either of the following options: ```sub.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_SORT_BY_NAME, Menu.NONE, "GridVu");
    sub.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_SORT_BY_ADDRESS, Menu.NONE, "Story");``` the imageview shows up @SachinBahukhandi

Answer (score 1):

Just do like.

```
Imageview.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

And

```
Imageview.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

Comment: This Worked or not @Marc Karam

Comment: I'm not sure where i would put your code.  because it's supposed to become visible when the user clicks on one of these menu options that show up
```sub.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_SORT_BY_NAME, Menu.NONE, "GridVu");
    sub.add(Menu.NONE, MENU_SORT_BY_ADDRESS, Menu.NONE, "Story");```

Comment: Just add my code to onclick of view where the menu is present... for eg. If menu is a listview then add the code to onclick of listview

Answer (score 0):

I think OnClickListener would not work instead `OnContextItemSelected` would help you out:

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

 switch (item.getItemId()) {
 case CONTEXT_MENU_VIEW:
    any_function();//add your functionality here i.e. what you want to do
    return true;
 case CONTEXT_MENU_EDIT:
    **confirmDelete**();
    return true;
 default:
    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
 }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You might want first to have a reference to your ImageView,

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private ImageView mImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // other codes

        // R.id.imageView3 where imageView3 is the ID in 
        // <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        mImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView3);

        // other codes
    }

    // other codes
}
```

Then on `onContextItemSelected` (as decripbed by @SachinBahukhandi) you can,

```
@Override
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()){
        case CONTEXT_MENU_VIEW:
            mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //mImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;

        case CONTEXT_MENU_EDIT:
            //mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //mImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;

        case MENU_SORT:
            //mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //mImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;

        case MENU_SORT_BY_NAME:
            //mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //mImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;

        case MENU_SORT_BY_ADDRESS:
            //mImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            //mImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            break;
    }

    return super.onContextItemSelected(item);
}
```

As per Android Documentation, [Use onContextItemSelected(android.view.MenuItem) to know when an item has been selected](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreateContextMenu%28android.view.ContextMenu,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo%29).